# Can I have a straightforward constructor generated from declarations only?

Tags: c++, constructor, instance-variables, c-preprocessor

I have a class with many instance variables:

```
class Data {
public:
    const double a, b, c, d;
    const size_t e, f, g, h, i, j;
    const std::string s;
    // and so on
    double Q, Z;
    Data(const double a, const double b, ...);
};
```

and some fairly involved logic elsewhere in the code which computes the values all these fields should have and then creates a `Data` object.

```
double a = ...;
double b = ...;
// and so on, but not for Q and Z
Data data_instance(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, s, ...);
```

The values of `Q` and `Z` are computed in the constructor, as functions of the other values. I do it this way because instances of `Data` are meant to be immutable, and I would like the fields to be `const` to help the compiler enforce this.

As far as I know, this requires me to define a constructor

```
Data::Data(const double a, const double b, ...) : a(a), b(b), ... {}
```

which is not *really* a problem, but with ~35 fields, that's a lot of code that is all very formulaic, and could in principle be automatically generated. Is there any way I could exploit either a trick of C++ syntax or the preprocessor to do this? Specifically, I would like to give the list of fields *once*, in some form, and have the declarations, the parameters in the constructor, and the initializers in the constructor all generated automatically. This way when I have to add a new field to the class (which I do have to do from time to time, as I add new features), I only have to remember to add that new field in one place.

Or would it likely be better to just abandon the idea of `const`-correctness entirely? If I did that, I could create the `Data data_instance()` using a default constructor and *then* compute the values and assign them directly to its fields. That way I'd only have to declare the variables, not initialize them in the constructor. (If I could, say, have fields marked as `const` but somehow make them still able to be modified in the body of the constructor, that would work out for me.)

Comment: IMO the real problem is that your class has 35 fields, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Borgleader I heard that some companies deal whippings for creating new classes. And new files? They'll have to deal with the Gates Of Mordor build system!

Comment: IMO, there's no way other than this for const data members...

Comment: @Borgleader I hope you'll agree that this is better than the alternative of creating a method with 40 parameters. ;-) (actually: there would be 10 or 15 methods, each with the same 40 parameters)

Comment: You can group related items in their own classes.

Comment: @rightføld I don't see how that would help, since then I'd just have an instance which contains other instances which contain numbers, which introduces an extra level of indirection when I go to access them, all for no benefit in code clarity or performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is really just a trivial data "holder", consider making it an aggregate instead.

```
struct Data { // class works equally well...
    double a, b, c, d;
    size_t e, f, g, h, i, j;
    std::string s;
};
```

Now you use it:

```
Data const d { 0,1,2,3, 111,222,333,444,555,666, "hello world" };
```

Note how `d.s` is a `std::string const&`, because the `const` distributes across the instance's members.

Comment: Designated initialisers are also quite fun if you allow language extensions.

Comment: That would probably work. Though I forgot to mention in the question (and I'll edit to reflect this shortly) that there are a couple of fields which are initialized not by passing in a value, but by calculating something based on the values that were passed in. E.g. there is `double Q` which is initialized as `Q(exp(a)+exp(b))`. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @DavidZ Hardly. I'd suggest separation of concerns. I suppose you can handle 1 more of those _`10 or 15 methods, each with the same 40 parameters`_ to do the derived value calculations :)

Comment: @sehe I could, but I'd wind up doing the same calculation in nearly every method, and doing it millions of times when I only need to do it once. Given that the whole point of this is to avoid repeating code, I don't really like that idea.

Comment: Congratulations. You've completely missed the point. In no way does having another function mean you have to call it a zillion times. How about. .. one after initializing a new object of your datatype?

Comment: You were looking to avoid writing rote  code. So remove the rote part and don't change anything else